# Show existing post if no translation instead of going to home page in polylang

Tags: wordpress, lang, polylang

I'm using Polylang to support multiple languages on my site. Right now, if I'm on a post that say is in English and if I click a flag for which it has no translation (e.g. French), then I get taken to the home page in French. I don't want that. I want to stay on the  current post (or better yet, be shown the post in the default polylang language) and *not* taken to the home page.

I've looked into setting a language attribute `'lang' => pll_default_language()` in code somewhere, but I'm not really sure where to put it nor certain it would prevent the improper navigation to the home page. Does anyone know how to achieve this?